# How to set value in all row if value is null , use value in Max

Tags: mysql

I have a table, `Customers`
My table is 'Customers' 4 columns

```
CusttomerId  Name   ContactName Country
 1           Shere1  Ira        USA 
 2           Shere2  Jenny      Canada
 3           Shere3  Fill       Canada  
 4           Prod1   Joen       China 
 Null        Prod2   Clod       Russia 
 Null        Prod3   Brenda     Finland
 Null        Prod4   Katy       Belgium
```

in Column `CusttomerId` I need set value to all row is Null.
for example, after `CusttomerId = 4` next value must be `CusttomerId = 5` ,next row `CusttomerId = 6` ...

Help me, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get more help more quickly if you have a go yourself and post your attempt at solving your problem. Users won't respond to requests to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a mysql variable and  assigning the initial value by a query for max()

```
set @id := (select max(CusttomerId) from  Customers)
;
update Customers
set CusttomerId = (@id :=@id +1 )
where  CusttomerId is null 
;
```

Comment: You have a few typos. here's a working version: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/txgSda32KdKL4bhBqD5tcs/0

Comment: no worries would have been pointless me posting the same answer. Thanks though